# clickEvents numbers from API not matching WebUI

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk, python

The number of click events I retrieve from the FuelSDK API does not match the numbers I'm getting from the webUI. The API is giving me a lower number of click events compared to the webUI (4688 vs 8286 events).

I'm suspecting that the report from the webUI is giving me both regular + unique clicks, while the API is giving me only unique click events. How can I modify my prop properties to give me both regular + unique click events? I don't see anything in the documentation (https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/tracking/click-tracking.html#pythongetprops)

My python code:

```
fromDate = '2016-07-10T07:00:00.000'
toDate = '2016-07-13T07:00:00.000'

print '>>> Retrieve Filtered ClickEvents with GetMoreResults'
getClickEvent = ET_Client.ET_ClickEvent()
getClickEvent.auth_stub = stubObj   
getClickEvent.props = ["SendID","SubscriberKey","EventDate","Client.ID","EventType","BatchID","TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID","PartnerKey"]

from_filter = {'Property' : 'EventDate', 'SimpleOperator' : 'greaterThan', 'DateValue' : fromDate}
to_filter = {'Property' : 'EventDate', 'SimpleOperator' : 'lessThan', 'DateValue' : toDate}
getClickEvent.search_filter = {'LeftOperand' : from_filter  , 'LogicalOperator': 'AND', 'RightOperand' : to_filter}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ClickEvent retrieved through the API contains all clicks, it doesn't differentiate between unique versus duplicate because it is raw data.

When looking at the Web UI, how are you viewing the data there? Based on a single Job or is this for a triggered send?  The filter is looking at all click events across all emails so it might be helpful to modify that to match more closely with the tracking screen being used for comparison.

Comment: When on the WebUI, I am creating a "Subscriber Engagement" report and getting back a CSV file that contains all subscriber click, send, and open email events, for a specified date range. The WebUI doesn't have a setting that specifies a single job or triggered send.

It's important to note that I am creating a report under "Tracking --> Reports --> My Reports --> Subscriber Reports --> Subscriber Engagement". If this report doesn't reflect what the API is giving me, can you explain how they are different?